# Removing a character from elements in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my application `NSMutableArray` comes like this,

```
 Activity:(
"0-1",
"2-4",
"3-5",
"1-2"
)
```

I want data in `NSMutableArray` Like,

```
Activity:(
"1",
"4",
"5",
"2"
)
```

Please, Any one suggest me how can i do that?

Comment: CAPS MUCH? Seriously though,please use proper capitalization in your posts.

Comment: I also strongly suggest you learn basic algorithms and string-manipulation, as this is a very beginner question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I agree with Richard's comment.
Also, it's a bad habit naming your ivars capitalized.
That said, you can accomplish what you need with something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *cleanArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];  

// Here 'Activity' is your NSArray. A better name would be 'activity'
// (save capitalized names for classes)
for (NSString *item in Activity)
{
    [cleanArray addObject:[[item componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject]];
}
```

And now you got an array with the substrings after the '-' so you could just replace your original array with the new one.

Comment: @Alladinian But it remove only one value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a loop:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = ...
for (int i = 0 ; i != arr.count ; i++) {
    NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    str = [str substringFromIndex:2];
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:str];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code...

```
NSMutableArray *arra = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

let say activity array has the your initial array;

```
for(NSString *str in Activity){
     str  = [str substringFromIndex:str.length-1];
     [arra addObject:str];
}
[Activity removeAllObjects];
[Activity addAllObjectsFromArray:arra ];
[arra release];//If you are not using ARC
NSLog(@"Now your Activity array =%@",Activity );
```

and if yount to replace just "-" in your array then you can use this code..

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"
                                 withString:@""];
```

may this will help you..